# Understanding the definition of injectivity

Tags: functions

Regarding the following definition of injective function

> A function $f$ is injective on $(a, b)$ if whenever $x, y \in (a, b)$ and $x \neq y$ then $f(x) \neq f(y)$.

I am confused why $x$ can't be equal to $y$. I am also confused of what $f(x) \neq f(y)$ mean.

Comment: if $x=y$ then obviously $f(x)=f(y)$ hold for all function $f$... maybe a more clear definition of injectivity would be : $f$ is injective if for all $x,y\in (a,b)$, $$f(x)=f(y)\implies x=y.$$

Comment: $f(x) \neq f(y)$ is defined to be "not $f(x) = f(y)$" here.

Comment: Intuitively, injective means distinct points map to distinct points.

Comment: Suppose you want to tell someone you have a function that doesn't map any two distinct points to the same point. How would you define that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is that $x$ *can* be equal to $y$, but *if* $x$ is not equal to $y$ *then* $f(x)$ is not equal to $f(y)$.

"If" introduces a hypothetical.

We understand that $x$ and $y$ may be the same, and they may be different. But just suppose $x \ne y$. Then because $f$ is an injection, $f(x) \ne f(y)$.

What if there happen to be particular values of $x$ and $y$ such that $x \ne y$, but $f(x) = f(y)$? Then there are two elements of the domain which both map to the same element in the range. But then that means that $f$ is not an injection.

If $f$ is an injection, and if $x \ne y$, *whatever* $x$ and $y$ happen to be, then $f(x) \ne f(y)$ because that's what it means to be an injection.